# mysql - Automatically calculate number of missing and blank in schema

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a piece of code which calculate the number of missing and blank in my schema.

My idea is to use concat to create the script to calculate the numbers on one column then to loop accross the number of rows.

Creating a table with the instructions to execute is ok but I struggle with the loop. When including P1 in the script, nothing happen.

Any idea?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS workspace.instructions;
CREATE TABLE workspace.instructions (
  instructions varchar(3000)
) ;

insert into  workspace.instructions
select 
CONCAT('insert into  workspace.missing_rows
select
    sum(case when ', column_name, ' is null then 1 else 0 end) as nb_missing,
    sum(case when ', column_name,' = "" then 1 else 0 end) as nb_blank,
    "', table_name, '" as table_name0,
    "', column_name, '" as column_name0
from my_schema.', table_name, '; ') as instruction
    from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_table' and DATA_TYPE = 'varchar';
-- 57 rows

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS workspace.missing_rows;
CREATE TABLE workspace.missing_rows (
  table_name0 varchar(64),
  column_name0 varchar(64),
    nb_missing int,
    nb_blank int
) ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS workspace.test_loop;
CREATE TABLE workspace.test_loop (
  test varchar(1500)
) ;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS doiterate;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate(p1 INT)
BEGIN
  label1: LOOP
    SET p1 = p1 + 1;

    SELECT @s = (select instructions from workspace.instructions limit p1, 1);

    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
    EXECUTE stmt1; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 

    IF p1 < 57 THEN ITERATE label1; END IF;

    LEAVE label1;
  END LOOP label1;
END;

call doiterate(0);

select * from workspace.missing_rows;
```

Comment: Not glorious, but copied/paste workspace.instructions into SQL IDE. Worked perfectly. Still curious why it is not working, though.